# Remove check all/none checkbox from Reactable table

Tags: css, r

I want to remove the check all/none checkbox from a Reactable table.
In this image, I do not want the orange circled checkbox to appear.
[image]

Using Chrome Inspector, I examine the css of this checkbox and set `display: none;`
[image]

This removes the entire column of checkboxes. How do I remove just this one?

R Script

```
library(reactable)

reactable(iris,
          onClick = "select",
          selection = "multiple")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can append some javascript code and make it run when the reactable is rendered:
ie

```js
// Hide  the select all check box
document.querySelector('.rt-select-input[aria-label="Select all rows"]').parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "none";
```

#### The final R-code

```r
library(reactable)
library(htmlwidgets)
e<-reactable(iris,
          onClick = "select",
          selection = "multiple")

javascript <- JS('
document.querySelector(\'.rt-select-input[aria-label="Select all rows"]\').parentElement.parentElement.style.display="none";
')



(p <- prependContent(e,onStaticRenderComplete(javascript)))
```

### Improvements

In order to streamline the process and specifically target the wanted checkbox (as the aforementioned method would be unsuccessful when handling 2 tables in the same page) I wrote a function that'll dynamically target the wanted checkbox:

```r
hide.select.all <- function(x){
  javascript <- JS(paste0('
  let id = null;
  for (const script of document.querySelectorAll("script[data-for]")) {
    if(script.text.includes("', x$x$tag$attribs$dataKey ,'")) {
      id="#" + script.dataset.for;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(id) document.querySelector(id + \' .rt-select-input[aria-label="Select all rows"]\').parentElement.parentElement.style.display="none";
  ')) 
   prependContent(x,onStaticRenderComplete(javascript))
}

hide.select.all(e)
```

Comment: The appearance of the check all/none checkbox is gone. However, the behaviour is still there if you click in the same area.

Comment: Naively, I asked my question without mentioning that I needed this to work in a Shiny app. Shiny doesn't like this solution. My new question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63984876/remove-all-none-checkbox-from-reactable-table-in-shiny-app