# Hide and disable all/none checkbox from Reactable table and maintain column alignment

Tags: r, shiny, reactable

I wish to remove the all/none checkbox from a Reactable table in a Shiny app. @Abdessabour Mtk has provided a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63984876/remove-all-none-checkbox-from-reactable-table-in-shiny-app).

However, when the checkbox is actually removed, the header row shifts left and the left-alignment of the columns is impacted.

Is it possible to hide and disable the checkbox and thus not suffer from the column misalignment? Also, the shading of the header should carry over to the space above the column of checkboxes.

This R script shades the header row and removes the checkbox. You can see the misalignment of the Sepal.Length and Sepal.Width columns. If you comment out the `tags$head...` you see the columns in proper alignment.

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)

ui <- fluidPage(reactableOutput("table"),
                
                tags$head(tags$script(HTML('
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    document.querySelector(\'#table .rt-select-input[aria-label="Select all rows"]\').parentElement.parentElement.style.display="none";
                }, 200)
        ')))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  output$table <- renderReactable({ 
    reactable(iris,
              onClick = "select",
              selection = "multiple",
              columns = list(
                "Sepal.Length" = colDef(align = "left"),
                "Sepal.Width" = colDef(align = "left")
              ),
              defaultColDef = colDef(
                headerStyle = list(background = "brown"))
    )  
  })
  
}  
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The link to the solution is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay basically all that is needed to change is `display = "none"` to `visibility = "hidden"` i.e :

```
ui <- fluidPage(reactableOutput("table"),
    actionButton("button", "refresh"),
    tags$head(tags$script(HTML('
            setTimeout(()=>{
                document.querySelector(\'#table .rt-select-input[aria-label="Select all rows"]\').parentElement.parentElement.style.visibility="hidden";
            }, 125)
    ')))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  output$table <- renderReactable({ 
    reactable(iris,
              onClick = "select",
              selection = "multiple")
    })
    observeEvent(input$button, {
    output$table <- renderReactable({ 
    reactable(mtcars,
              onClick = "select",
              selection = "multiple")
        })
    })
}  
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

## version that works with shading

```
ui <- fluidPage(reactableOutput("table"),
                actionButton("button", "refresh"),
                tags$head(tags$script(HTML('
            setTimeout(()=>{
                div=document.createElement("div");
                div.style="background: brown; flex: 36 0 auto; width: 36px; max-width: 36px;";
                rep= document.querySelector(\'#table .rt-select-input[aria-label="Select all rows"]\').parentElement.parentElement;
                div.style.background=rep.style.background;
                div.className = "rt-th";
                rep.replaceWith(div);
            }, 140)
    ')))
)
server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  output$table <- renderReactable({ 
    reactable(iris,
              onClick = "select",
              selection = "multiple",
              columns = list(
                "Sepal.Length" = colDef(align = "left"),
                "Sepal.Width" = colDef(align = "left")
              ),
              defaultColDef = colDef(
                headerStyle = list(background = "brown"))
    )  
  })
  
}  
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Is it possible to keep the shading of the header row? I've added an example below your solution.

Comment: @ixodid you should edit the question. I'm working on an answer.

Comment: Very impressive @Abdessabour Mtk. My understanding of the 140-200ms timer is that we are waiting for the page to load before we can modify it. At 140ms, sometimes, the all/none checkbox appears. It would be better to be certain that the JavaScript runs only after the table or page has loaded. Is there a way to guarantee this programmatically with `onload=`?

Comment: If you return to the first post you'll find that I tried the event handling way, but shiny somehow fails to call them on the first occurence. And "DOMContentLoaded" fails because it's fired before the loading of the content.

Answer (score 1):

An answer that does not depend on timing is offered by the creator of Reactable, [here](https://github.com/glin/reactable/issues/83).